# After loop, data is not what expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Probably missing something really obvious here but spent ages testing it out and can't figure out what is going on.

I'm trying to run through each item in an array (dataArray), split this up and put it in a temp array. Then go through this temp array and create a temp object using some column names I have in another array (columnNames). Then push this temp object into an array of objects (products).

```
e.g.   
col names ['A', 'B', 'C']  
temparray ['a', 'a', 'a']  
into ==>
products [{'A':'a','B':'b','C':'c'}]
```

This works ok, the array I get at the end contains the correct number of objects but they are all the same object (the last one that is processed). When I console.log each tempObj I can see that they are different but for some reason this is not reflected in the final array.

Any ideas?

```
    var tempArray = [],
    tempObj = {};
    //run through each row if there is data
    if (dataArray != null || dataArray != []) {
      try {
        for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
          //split row by ','
          tempArray = dataArray[i].split(',');

          for (var y = 0; y < tempArray.length; y++) {

            tempObj[columnNames[y]] = tempArray[y];
            //onsole.log(tempObj[columnNames[y]]);
          }
          console.log(tempObj);
          products[i] = tempObj;
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      } finally {
        console.log(products);
        console.log("Seperated into " + products.length + " products...");
        ProductUpdater(products, merchantID)
      }
    }
  }
```

note: aswell as using "products[i] = tempObj" to add it to the array I have tried .push with no luck.

Comment: You keep reusing and updating the same `tempObj`. Create a different one for every object you want to add to the Array. JS never copies composite data types (Objects and Arrays) on assignment. It only copies a reference to the data.

Comment: You also have a problem with this test `dataArray != []` because `[] === []` is `false` as they are not the same `object`. If you want to check if `dataArray` is empty then check the `length`

Comment: And you may want to consider [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) if that is suitable for `dataArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to squint :

Had to move the declaration of the tempObj into the first for loop.

```
var tempArray = [];

    //run through each row if there is data
    if (dataArray != null || dataArray != []) {
      try {
        for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
          var tempObj = {};
          //split row by ','
          tempArray = dataArray[i].split(',');

          for (var y = 0; y < tempArray.length; y++) {

            tempObj[columnNames[y]] = tempArray[y];
            //onsole.log(tempObj[columnNames[y]]);
          }
          //console.log(tempObj.ean);
          products[i] = tempObj;
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      } finally {
        console.log(products);
        console.log("Seperated into " + products.length + " products...");
        ProductUpdater(products, merchantID)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Might as well do `var tempArray = dataArray[i].split(',');` too, since it's not needed in the outer scope anyway (and the `split` will make it useless in that outer scope)